# general triangle angles and lengths

Tags: geometry, triangles

Pythagoras shows us for a right angled triangle how to find the remaining side length where the lengths connected by 90 degrees are known.

But more-so there is a surprisingly short equation that I can't find that gives the remaining length where any two lengths are known. What is this equation?

Are there other equations relating the internal angles of two corners and the third, if so what are they?

Comment: I think we should better call him Pythagoras. And, corners could well be vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know all angles and two of the sides, you can choose between two different rules for finding the third side. Both apply to general triangles:

- The [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines): $a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C=c^2$. This can be thought of as a generalization of Pythagoras' theorem because the cosine term vanishes when $C$ is a right angle.
- The [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines): $\frac{\sin C}{c}=\frac{\sin A}{a}$. This can be solved for $c$ to get $c=a\frac{\sin C}{\sin A}$.

If you google for [solving triangles](http://www.google.com/search?q=solving+triangles) you will find numerous walk-throughs of how to find the entire triangle depending on what you already know about it. The first hit for me is [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html), which looks good.

In general you need three pieces of information, where a "piece" is either the length of a side or an angle. Three pieces also turn out to be *sufficient* except in the AAA case (you know all angles and no length, so any solution can be scaled by an arbitrary abount and still be a solution) and the SSA case (where you know to sides and one of the angles, but not the angle where the known sides meet; then there can be two different solutions).

Comment: Nice hint :) I've marked this answer as correct. This edit is part of fixing various small issues in the post. This really is a good open helpfull answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given two lengths of a general tringle and the angle betwen them you can calculate the third length by use of the [Law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos\gamma},\quad$ for $\, a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos\gamma>0$

Comment: +1 for being the most general and providing a relatively straightforward equation. Does γ represent the angle between the two known lengths? Can this be rearranged in terms of c not squared like this? c=sqrt(a²+b²−2*a*b*cos(γ))

Comment: Yes, both is correct.

Comment: tyvm. For others reading this, Wolfram style info on the law of cosines mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ be two vectors corresponding to sides of a triangle. Then the third side is $\vec{c} = \vec{a} - \vec{b}$.

$$
  || \vec{c} ||^2 = \langle \vec{c}, \vec{c} \rangle = \langle \vec{a}-\vec{b}, \vec{a}-\vec{b} \rangle = \langle \vec{a}, \vec{a} \rangle + \langle \vec{b}, \vec{b} \rangle -2 \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle = | \vec{a} |^2 + |\vec{b} |^2 - 2 | \vec{a} | \cdot | \vec{c} | \cdot \cos \angle(\vec{a}, \vec{b})
$$

Comment: also good, thank you